# How interpret keras training loss without compare with validation loss?

Tags: python, keras, training-data

I have several implementation of the same neural network, but each one with different starting parameter.

[image]

This is one of my plot comparing the training loss of the base experiment with the training loss of another experiment.

I have also other exaples:

[image]
[image]

May anyone point me to some instruction on how understand these output from the keras fit()? Note that I don't have any validation set.

Thanks

Comment: This might help:[https://blog.algorithmia.com/introduction-to-loss-functions/](https://blog.algorithmia.com/introduction-to-loss-functions/)

Comment: @Raguel I don't see the point... or the connection. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, your loss have weirs spikes and even increases in value....

I can imagine a few reasons:

- The functions you created are not continuous or have weird behavior, like spikes and other things that might trick the idea decreasing the loss. This includes big contrasts between flat and steep regions.
- You're using a weird custom optimizer
- Your learning rate is too big